# How to look for directory in http address

Tags: linux, shell, regular-expression, wget, ftp

I'm trying to create a regex formula in shell script which will allow me to find desired folder in HTTP directory.

Let's assume that this is the address:  `ftp://google.com/directories/`
In this directory a lot of different directories are placed.

The names of the folders looks like this:

```
A10W10
A10W11
A9W9
A11W9
A11W23
```

I want to find with regex the newest folder, in this case `A11W23`.

I do not know how to search through HTTPS directories.

I only find something which allows me to download the files from directory

```
wget --spider -r --no-parent ftp://google.com/directories/A11W23
ls -l A11W23
```

How to create a regex for desired HTTP destination?

Comment: You will not necessarily be able to list and parse out all the objects in the directory if the web server is configured to disable directory indexing. This is a common security concern and is often disabled.

Comment: A regular expression is a pattern, and there are tools to check whether a string matches a pattern specified by a regular expression.  For example, “ant”, “elk”, “ibis”, “opossum” and “uniform” all match the regular expression `[aeiou].*` (and “bat”, “cat”, “dog”, “fox” … do not).  A regular expression cannot be used to determine which of a collection of strings is the newest.  Also, please try to define precisely what you mean by “newest”.

Comment: newest -> number after letters is the highest. e.g. A11 is greater than A10, later on I'm looking by selecting highest number next to letter W -> W10 is greater than W9

Comment: You say http(s) address, but the address is `ftp://` ?!